# GAE backup, Blob fields vs. Blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, backup, blob, blobstore

Google's documentation states the following on their help page for Backup/Restore, Copy and Delete Data:

> Note: Blob data is not backed up by this backup feature!

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin#Backup_And_Restore

I did a simple backup/restore with an entity type in my application that contains a Blob field. After I backed up the entity, I removed the data that was stored in the Blob field. When I restored the entity it had that data once again.

Is it safe to infer that the warning in the documentation refers to data in the Blobstore and not Blob fields of entities stored in the normal data store?

Comment: Was the data in the blob field binary or text?

Comment: String...stored using pickle.dumps()

Comment: So it was binary. Your assumption seems correct. Maybe a googler will come answer authoritatively.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it is safe to assume the two are not related.  As per the google [Blobstore Java API Overview](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview):

Note: Blobs as defined by the Blobstore service are not related to blob property values used by the datastore.